# On a new Telescope installation on a Laravel project, Localhost:8000/telescope returns blank page

Tags: json, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to get Telescope working on my project. When I try to navigate, on Chrome, to Localhost:8000/telescope I get a blank page. I tracked down the error to laravel/telescope/resources/views/layout.blade.php.

```
 <!-- Global Telescope Object -->
<script>
  window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);
</script>
```

The developer console error I get:

```
window.Telescope 
 = {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;telescope&quot;,&quot;timezone&quot;:&quot;UTC&quot;,&quot;recording&quot;:true};
```

My major concern is to find a solution to this. I also would like to know why this error happened. I couldn't find a similar problem through google.

Comment: I'm using /telescope.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. The error you posted doesn't look like a JavaScript console error.

Answer (score 0):

After some further googling I was able to find the cause and solution. Found[here in this article](https://laravel-news.com/blade-double-encoding-vue-components) of a very similar problem on Laravel and Vue.

By double encoding, the JSON object the HTML entities are removed from the object. The article suggests setting blade double encoding in the AppServiceProvider.

`class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::doubleEncode();
    }
}`

Another solution that I used was to double encode inline in the layout.blade.php.

```
<!-- Global Telescope Object -->
<script>
 window.Telescope = {!!json_encode($telescopeScriptVariables)!!}
 // window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);
</script>
```